# Maven install dont create sources in classes folder

Tags: java, maven

Good morning. I ve got a problem with maven. The problem is that, when I run maven install , the generated WAR dont include the classes.I think that my project is not taking the correct route of my classes. My project structure is:

```
project_name
       src
        -package name
        -package name
       WebContent
           -Meta-Inf
       WEB-INF
         - lib(is emptly because im using maven)
         -  web.xml
       pom.xml
```

Anyone knows why maven do this sometimes? I mean, why is not creating my classes in the generated war. I put the code of the pom.xml and web.xml.
Note: the web.xml  im not using it. My project is a web-service and its created as a maven project, however I included as dynamic web project in PROJECT FACETS. I have to say that my project is working fine I only have this problem with maven. Anyone can give more information about this?? Thanks. I can put more information if is needed.

Code of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>WS_ECI</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Code of pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.rest.eci.cliente</groupId>
  <artifactId>WS_ECI</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WS_ECI</name>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

    <properties>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <org.springframework-version>2.5</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20131018</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
              <groupId>EnvioEventos</groupId>
              <artifactId>EnvioEventos</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Maybe directory layout is wrong. Should be src-main-java. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: No, i tried yesterday. And its useless.

Comment: But im still thinking that must be something of the directory.

Comment: Im going to try to create a new maven project and add the sources of my project, maybe i can solve in this way

Comment: OK, i tried with a correct new maven project configuration. The errors disappears but now i get this.    found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String....  I think its for java version and compiler i tried with several versions but the errors still here, im going to try how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its everyting all right the WAR includes the files it was my fault that i couldnt see the classes inside the folder. Its not neccesary that the directory must be src/main/java.

Comment: You should follow the conventions which mean `src/main/java`etc. which makes life easier.